# how to reduce loading time of galleria theme

Tags: load, themes, galleria

I have integrated galeria to show images in my cakephp application.It works fine.But after each "Next" click the pictures come with bit delay.I want the image to come as soon as it clicked.Every other thing works faster and fine.Each queries are optimised.I checked thouroughly for anyother cause.but everything is fine.The list of images i am showing in my galeria application are with large size and the number of images are also more.
Does the loading time depend on size of image or number of images or both?
On what factor the loading time depends? 
How to reduce loading time of galleria theme?

Comment: Not a very specific question. Though I doubt it is programming related anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galleria has an [optimization page](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/references/optimize/), where they recommend the following for themes:

> We generally recommend you to use the Galleria.loadTheme method to load themes because it’s really convenient and makes it easier to switch themes. However, you might get a snappier result if you include the theme javascript in the head tag, especially if it’s minified together with the rest of your scripts.
>
> You can also add the theme CSS file as a  tag to make it load faster. Just make sure you give it the id ‘galleria-theme’.